# product component (Ecommerce project) gets deleted after refreshing the productDetails page... React js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, mern

So I'm a beginner in MERN stack and have been following a tutorial to build an e-commerce website. But I'm having some trouble with productDetails page in the frontend. So when I click on the product it shows its detail page but after refreshing the page goes blank, and again after going back to home page the product just gets deleted or disappears...Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

This is the productDetails.js code

```
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from '../../actions/productAction';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const ProductDetails = ({match}) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const { product, loading, error} = useSelector(
  (state) => state.productDetails);

useEffect( () => {

  dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));

}, [dispatch, match.params.id]);


return (
  <Fragment>
    <div className="ProductDetails">

      <div>
          <Carousel>

            {
              product.images &&
              product.images.map((item, i) => (
                <img 
                className="CarouselImage" 
                key={item.url}
                src={item.url}
                alt={`${i} Slide`}
                />

              ))
            }
          </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
  
);
};

export default ProductDetails
```

This the Home.js code

```
import { CgMouse } from "react-icons/cg";
import "./Home.css";
import Product from "./Product.js"
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import { getProduct } from "../../actions/productAction";
import { useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";





const Home = () => {
  const alert = useAlert();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

  const { loading, error, products, productsCount } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.products);

  useEffect (() => {
    if (error) {
      return alert.error(error);
      
    }
    dispatch(getProduct());
  }, [dispatch, error, alert]);
 

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
      
        
      <MetaData title="ECOMMERCE" />

          <div className="banner">
            <p>Welcome to Ecommerce</p>
            <h1>FIND AMAZING PRODUCTS BELOW</h1>

            <a href="#container">
              <button>
                Scroll <CgMouse />
              </button>
            </a>
          </div>

        <h2 className="homeHeading">Featured Products</h2>

        <div className="container" id="container">
        {products &&
              products.map(product => (
              <Product product={product} />
                
              ))}

            
           
        </div>
            

    </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Also the product.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactStars from "react-rating-stars-component";



const Product = ({ product }) => {
  const options = {
    edit: false,
    color: "rgba (20,20,20,0.1)",
    activeColor: "tomato",
    size: window.innerWidth < 600 ? 20 : 25,
    value:product.ratings,
    isHalf:true
};
  return (
    <Link className='productCard' to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
        <img src={product.images[0].url} alt={product.name} />
        <p>{product.name}</p>
        <div>
            <ReactStars {...options} /> <span> ({product.numOfReviews} Reviews) </span>
        </div>
        <span>{`₹${product.price}`}</span>
    </Link>
    
  );
};

export default Product
```

These are the error I'm getting

```
       Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    at Carousel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:254237:5)
    at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:7092:31)
    at div
    at div
    at ProductDetails (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1188:5)
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:259420:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:259622:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:259039:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:257794:35)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:277:48)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:19626:23)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:255302:20)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:67
error @ react-dom.development.js:43
warnAboutUpdateOnUnmountedFiberInDEV @ react-dom.development.js:23914
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21840
enqueueSetState @ react-dom.development.js:12467
push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState @ react.development.js:365
(anonymous) @ Carousel.js:313
setTimeout (async)
setActive @ Carousel.js:312
componentDidMount @ Carousel.js:217
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20663
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
(anonymous) @ index.js:16
./src/index.js @ index.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:851
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ store.js:23
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:851
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 
    
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/product/%3Canonymous%3E 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: check your `match.params.id`. it might be undefined when you reload the page.

Comment: Would be easier to follow if the product.js file was also included

Answer (score 0):

the Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component is coming from any useEffect but i am not sure that it's in ProductDetails.js try the below code

```
const { id } = useParams();

useEffect( () => {
  dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
}, [dispatch, id]);
```

also this is not the way to use the effects as well.

```
useEffect (() => {

    dispatch(getProduct());

  }, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
     if (error) {
      alert.error(error);  // i am not sure why you return here I never used react-alert lib but I don't think you return it and add it as dep in array.
    }
}, [error])
```

try passing empty dep arrays in all `useEffect` to check the results.

Comment: The error still persists